# Add Link Next to Button in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add a link next to the button on the right side of the screen, on the same line.
I've tried various methods, but they all result in the link shown a line above or under.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #171515;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown show"><a id="dropdownMenuLink" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Select
</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></div>
</div>

<p><a href="#">Link on the right side</a></p>
```

Comment: I see no `button` tag

Comment: @LushModz can you provide a image to explain your idea?

Comment: https://imgur.com/KsJE0xs

Comment: @lushModz.I didnt see any button there.do you need dropdown with a button with same line?

Comment: Nah the text on the left is my dropdown menu, i need to add a link to the right side, on the same line. I probably shouldn't have used the word "button" my bad, thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

The easier and similar way to your css would be to give the paragraph position absolute, set top and right to 0.

```css
    .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #171515;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}

#right-link{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown show"><a id="dropdownMenuLink" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Select
</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></div>
</div>

<p id="right-link"><a href="#">Link on the right side</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added the code and it added the right side text to the top of my screen, any fix? I need them on the same line.

Comment: @LushModz2643 they're already on the same line if you check the code snippet, have you added `top: 0;` ?

Comment: Yes but on my website it's not on the same line

Comment: I'd advice you to remove the `<p></p>` tag and just give the id to the `<a></a>` tag, it will hopefully fix it. The paragraph forces break to a new line.
Put this instead `<a id="right-link" href="#">Link on the right side</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You could absolute-position your link, which would allow you to place it in a specific position on the document. Setting `right:0px` will allow you to align it to the right of the webpage. If you set the `margin-top` css property to the negative of your font-size, the link will be placed one line closer to the top of the webpage (or one line back from the default position). Since the default position is one line after the previous link, this will set your link to be on the same line as the link dropdown menu. Assuming your font is 1em, your updated code should be:

```css
     .dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      display: none;
      float: left;
      min-width: 160px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      margin: 2px 0 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: left;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: #171515;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
      border-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
      box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    }
```

```html
   <div class="dropdown show"><a id="dropdownMenuLink" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Select
</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></div>
</div>
<p style="position:absolute;right:0px;margin-top:-1em"><a href="#" style="">Link on the right side</a></p>
```

Comment: unfortunately this changed the text formatting for the whole site